# save in a macro the storage type of variables in a .dta dataset (without opening it)

Tags: stata

I'd like to save in a macro the storage type of variables in a .dta dataset (without opening it).

As an example I'll first create a dataset `temp.dta`

```
drop _all  
set obs 100
gen a = runiform()
save temp, replace
```

In an interactive session, I can display the storage type of all variable using the command `describe using`

[image]
However, the command only saves the dimension of the dataset, without any information related to storage types.

[image]

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Stata does not appear to provide this capability. You could write a program (in Stata or another language) to read the dta file directly and extract the <varnames> and <variable_types> information from the file header. From within Stata use `help dta` to get the full description of the dta file format for use in programming.

Comment: You could run `describe` within a log and extract the output from the log file. I don't know of an existing program to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with this example:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto

foreach v of varlist _all {
    local allt `allt' `v' `: type `v''
}

display "`allt'"
```

I set the information such that each variable name is followed by the type, but you can modify that to suit your needs; maybe two locals, one with variable names, the other with corresponding types is best for you.

The key is the *extended macro function* `type varname`. See `help extended_fcn`, for details.

For this to work, the dataset needs to be opened at some point. I don't know a way of doing this without the latter requirement.

### Edit

@SteveSamuels proposes `use <somedata> in 1`, and I present the benchmarking:

```
clear

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto
expand 50000

tempfile myauto
save "`myauto'"

*----- tests -----

clear

timer on 1
describe using "`myauto'"
timer off 1

clear

timer on 2
use "`myauto'" in 1
describe
timer off 2

clear

timer on 3
use "`myauto'"
describe
timer off 3

count
timer list

timer clear
clear
```

Resulting in

```
. timer list
   1:      0.00 /        1 =       0.0000
   2:      0.22 /        1 =       0.2190
   3:      0.33 /        1 =       0.3260
```

So, it is faster then a simple `use`, as expected, but `describe using ...` still wins the race. The latter must use optimized code and additionally, there must be some reason for `use <somedata> in 1` to be unexpectedly slow, despite loading only one observation.

This doesn't include, of course, looping through variables and using extended macro functions, nor parsing a log file; but I don't think results would be modified by much.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do this. For efficiency reason, I just don't want to open the dataset.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Unfortunately, I don't think that would be faster than parsing the log file. See my edit within the answer.

Comment: In a deleted comment, I had guessed that @Roberto's method would be faster than parsing the dta headers. I agree that parsing the log file would be faster.    As an aside:  `use mydata in 1` just now  took ~2 seconds to open a  2 GB data set I have at hand.

Comment: I don't think there is an efficiency gain in using "in 1" (at least on Mac OSX Stata 13). You need to be careful for timing: in MAC OSX, recent files are stored in the RAM, so when you "use" a file for the second time, it's almost instantanely loaded.

Comment: I can't speak for Mac machines, but for non-Mac, I think it is always the case that it is more efficient (at least a bit more). In the code given above, a `tempfile` is created and stored in the hard-drive (in the user defined or system defined _temp_ directory, or in the current directory). I speculate Stata will always pick it up from there, even if the operating system saves a copy in RAM; Stata being produced by serious people, and concerned about data corruptibility, would prefer it that way. Whichever the way, simple testing supports the idea that `... in 1` produces efficiency gains.

Comment: After a reboot, you can change the order of execution of the three subtests.
You could also run each subtest in its own do-file, with its own test data set, 
and guarantee three different physical files. The results come out the same.
Both experiments, confirm the efficiency gain. 
Like I mentioned before, it's not as big as one might expect, but I suspect it's statistically significant.